# "In every area" vs "in any area"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does this sentence

> "You do not have experience in **every** area we are looking for."

mean

"You have experience in some areas, but you lack experience in some other areas. "?

If the sentence is changed to

> "You do not have experience in **any** area we are looking for."

Does it mean that you are not good at anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sense of the meaning is correct.

> You do not have experience in **every** area we are looking for.

there are some areas which they are looking for which you do have experience and some areas which you do not have experience

> You do not have experience in **any** area we are looking for.

of the areas they are looking for you do not have experience in any of them

It does not generally mean you are not good ay anything, just possibly you have nothing to offer them without the particular experience.